# Swift SKAction Sequence not running

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

whats wrong with this?

```
    self.runAction(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock({
                print("Step 1")
            }),
            SKAction.waitForDuration( 2 ),
            SKAction.runBlock({
                print("step 2")
            }),
            SKAction.waitForDuration( 2 ),
            SKAction.runBlock({
                print("step 3")
            }),
        ])
    )
```

Step 1 prints to console, but step 2 and 3 do not - it seems that the first action gets run but all others do not.

thanks.

Does it have anything to do with my classes?

```
class Arrow: Entity{}
class Entity: SKSpriteNode
```

I'm calling the block of code from a function in the Arrow class.

Comment: Everything is fine with that code. What is the self in this case?

Comment: I thought it did, any ideas why print("step 2") might not print to console?

Comment: Do you have any other running code ? This code is valid and should work. Try it in the empty project and you'll see (I assumed that self is a current scene).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs :

> An SKAction object is an action that is executed by a node in the
>   scene

Means if the node is not added to the scene, the actions can't be executed.
So what is currently happening, is that your arrow (obviously) somehow is removed from the scene before your action sequence is completed. Also check if you are accidentally removing all actions (using `removeAllActions()` method) from an arrow node at some point. That could stop action execution as well.

Comment: its weird - the arrow is there i can see it!, however the player who spawns the arrow can run the code and get to step 2 - the but the arrow can not run the code itself

Comment: @garyconstable Then add more code which can reproduce the issue...This way everybody can just guess ;)